# Cronjob strato shopware

Tags: cron, hosting, shopware

Could someone help out,
working to disable the admin worker, but first i need to setup the cronjobs

php /pfad/zu/Shopware/bin/console scheduled-task:run --time-limit=295 --memory-limit=512M

is not working in strato

response : /bin/sh: /pfad/zu/Shopware/bin/console: No such file or directory

Same is for clear cache : php bin/console cache:clear

i have read the documentation but when adding ./ does fix the job
then it give 404 not found.

It would mean alot if its working auto haha

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well... the response is quite clear: *No such file or directory*. So the path  `/pfad/zu/Shopware/bin/console` you entered is not correct. When logged in to the server, check in which directory you were thrown in and start searching for the shopware-folder (which contains at least the subdirectories bin, config, custom, files, public, var and vendor). If found, enter `pwd` on the terminal, which should give you the correct path.